# How to: Place TXT File's Content (from FTP Server) in HTML5 Document

Tags: javascript, html, text, ftp

I am trying to get the content of a TXT file (located on my FTP server) to place it in a HTML5 document. Unfortunately, I just know how to read a txt file by selecting it with a dialog. Does someone of you know how to set the content of a txt file, that is located on my FTP server?

**Something like:**

```
<div src="ftp://john-doe.com/Ordner/Unterordner/txtFile1.txt" />
```

**Here is my content so far:**

```
<body>
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
<script>
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;

        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                return function (e) {
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = ['<p>', e.target.result, '</p>'].join('');
                    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                };
            })(f);

            reader.readAsText(f, "UTF-8");
            reader.readAsText(f);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Comment: I can't see any way of doing this without some sort of proxy in-between. Get your server to send you the file instead of doing this in Javascript.

Comment: You cannot do this as ftp is a different protocol then http(s) and thus violates the cross domain policy, so you cannot load the file unless you use some server side request. Not sure if you can setup a ftp server to allow for CORS (cross-origin resource sharing)

Comment: Server side request? Are there any documents or tutorials?

Comment: Its basically making an ajax request to a server script (like a php script) that loads the data from that url and returns that data. If you do not know what ajax is just google: ajax tutorials